# Why can't we say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm currently working with problems regarding uniform convergence. One of the problems I worked with were stated as the following:

> Supoose $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin x/n }{x}$ on the interval $I = [1,\infty)$. Show that the sequence of functions converges uniformly to $f(x) = 0$. Then, show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx = \pi/2 \neq \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$.

I managed to show that the $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = 0$. However, I always thought that this implies that we can interchange the order of limits for our integration. In other words, we can bring the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ inside the integrand, and solve for $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$, which in this case would yield us $0$.

In this case however, it seems to be that we get that this integral is equal to $\pi/2$. I'd be glad if you could explain to me why this doesnt work in this case.

Furthermore, I'll also present the solution to my integration. I hope you can give me feedback on that too.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x/n }{x} dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x/n }{x/n} dx$

We use the substitution $x/n = u$, and we get:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1/n}^{\infty} \frac{\sin u }{u} du$

Furthermore, it's given that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x }{x} dx = \pi/2$ and since $1/n$ tends to $0$ for our lower bound in the previous integral, we precisely get that our limit is equal to $\pi/2$.

Thank you.

Comment: Uniform convergence over a *bounded* interval allows you to interchange the order of integration and limit.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ohhh I see. Thank you alot :)

Comment: In general, in order to interchange the limit and integration, you have to guarantee that there is no "mass escaping towards infinity". This is guaranteed usually if (1) the functions are bounded in a "finite" region (such as in the uniform convergence over a bounded interval or dominated convergence), or (2) the function only grows towards one direction (such as in the monotone convergence). Unfortunately, uniform convergence over an infinite interval is not one of them and thus leaves a possibility of mass escaping towards infinity.

Comment: A simpler example of mass escaping to infinity is $f_n(x)= 1_{[0,n]}/n$